# How to convert Array of object to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, redux

I have an Array of a single  object and some objects inside that object 
I want to remove the first object and spread all objects into the array
I have this

```
friends: [
      {
    one: {
          id: 'one',
          address: 'something'
        },
   two: {
          id: 'two',
          roomID: 'something'
        },
   me: 'three'
      }
    ]
```

I want this...

```
friends: [
        {
          id: 'one',
          address: 'something'
        },
         {
          id: 'two',
          roomID: 'something'
        },
    ]
```

Comment: `data.friends = Object.values(data.friends[0]).filter(el => el.id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to `map` only properties `one` and `two`, then we can use them into params of `flatMap` method to get the desired result:

```
const result = friends.flatMap(({one, two}) =>([{...one}, {...two}]));
```

An example:

```js
let friends = [
    {
        one: {
            id: 'one',
            address: 'something'
        },
        two: {
            id: 'two',
            roomID: 'something'
        },
        me: 'three'
    }
];

const result = friends.flatMap(({one, two}) =>([{...one}, {...two}]));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

As you want to filter out the data to get only the object inside you can try this

```
Object.values(req).filter(ele=>{
    if((ele instanceof Object) && !(ele instanceof Array)){
        return ele
    }
})
```

where `req` is `friends[0]` from

```
friends: [
      {
    one: {
          id: 'one',
          address: 'something'
        },
   two: {
          id: 'two',
          roomID: 'something'
        },
   me: 'three'
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Quicky.

```
Object.keys(friends[0]).map(key => Object.prototype.toString.call(friends[0][key]) === '[object Object]' ? friends[0][key] : null).filter(x => x)
```